# Find all substring of a string of size n in java

Tags: java, string

This is my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class String3 {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        int l=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<=s.length();i++) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(i,i+l));
        }
    }
 }
```

I am getting these errors

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
begin 6, end 9, length 8    at
java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(Unknown Source)  at
java.base/java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)    at
String3.main(String3.java:9)
```

Comment: change to `for(int i=0;i<s.length() - l;i++)`  Also I would change the variable `l` to something easier to read and understand - remember that good code should be self-documenting

Comment: Yes code is now working perfectly. Thank you so much @ Scary Wombat

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String s=sc.nextLine();
int len=sc.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<=s.length() - len;i++) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(i,i+len));
}
```

Comment: if the input is "welcometojava" then i should get output like  wel  elc  lco  com ome met eto toj oja jav ava .But when i am using s.length() -len-1 i am not getting last two substring.

Comment: could you please explain me why you are subtracting size of the substring from the length of the original string?

Comment: No, I am not.  I am only looping up to that point as you are `adding` to the inputted `len` to the substring

Answer (score -1):

The error says,

```
begin 6, end 9, length 8
```

which means you are trying to access the stubstring (6 to 9) of a string whose length is just 8.

The `length()` method returns the actual length and not the 0-indexed length (which might be confusing in the beginning)

So changing the `<=` to just `<` in your for loop should fix it.

Comment: Yes you are right. But i think  problem is not only the relational operator.